# Заменить текст в теге по id PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, пишу что-то типа магазина аккаунтов, и решил замутить несложную авторизацию, через vk-api ведь не сильно хочу париться с mysql и хостинг бесплатный не поддерживает :) Вопрос в авторизации, решил что бы не переделывать всю страницу в PHP просто подключу скрипт который будет контролировать только кнопку входа (ну типа если пользователь уже вошел там пишеться его имя и при нажатии ссылка на личный кабинет).

```
<h3 id="auth">Войти</h3>
```

Нужно программным методом заменить "Войти" на "Вы вошли".
Яваскрипт не предлогать)

Comment: `и хостинг бесплатный не поддерживает` - давно все по дефолту mysql поддерживают. если это не какой-то конструктор сайтов

Comment: Многие бесплатные хостинги не поддерживают mysql

Comment: Но яваскрипт обижаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При авторизации дать пользователю в сессию значение с его айдишником, или любое другое, и в зависимости от этого подключать нужный файл с кнопкой.

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = '12345';
```

И проверять

```
if( isset($_SESSION['user_id'] )
    include 'login.php';
else
    include 'not_login.php';
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego буферизация в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Буферизация + регулярка, и будет на выходе требуемый результат

```
<?php

session_id() ?: session_start();
ob_start();

?>

<h3 id="auth">Войти</h3>

<?php

// Допустим, id юзера вы сохранили в сессию
$_SESSION['id'] = 1;
$content = '';

if (!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $patt = '~(<h3 id="auth">)Войти(</h3>)~';
    $content = preg_replace($patt, '$1Вы вошли$2' , $content);
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego хорошо :)

Comment: @pavel1787mego `$content = '<h3 id="auth">Войти</h3>';  $patt = '~(<h3 id="auth">)Войти(</h3>)~';
    $content = preg_replace($patt, '$1Вы вошли$2' , $content);`

Comment: @pavel1787mego кстати, почему у вас не работает код из моего ответа? Перед его публикацией я его конечно же проверял - проблем не было.